# Finite OUTER measure and measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Royden's Real Analysis (4th edition), problem #19 (Chapter 2.5):

**Let $E$ have a finite OUTER measure. Show that if $E$ is not measurable, then there is an open set $O$ containing $E$ that has a finite outer measure and for which $m^{*}(O - E) > m^*(O)-m^*(E)$.**

My question is how can a set of finite measure be not measurable? I know that every set of finite positive measure harbors non-measurable **subsets**, but how could the **whole set** $E$ be not measurable when it has a finite measure by assumption?

Thanks.

I have righted the above problem. Sorry all!

Comment: It makes no sense. Something is missing for sure.

Comment: $E$ has finite measure and then we should consider if $E$ is not measurable???   I think you meant: "Let $E$ have finite **outer** measure. ...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably supposed to say "Let $E$ have finite outer measure".

There's an errata list [here](http://www.math.umd.edu/~pmf/err130405.pdf).  There is no entry for this problem, but the entry for problem 18 on page 43 looks similar to this problem and is supposed to start "Let $E$ have finite outer measure".

Comment: My mistake. I misread: it does say finite "outer" measure. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Since $E$ is not measurable, we know by Theorem 11 (Royden 4th edition) that there exists an $\epsilon > 0$
such that for any open set $O$ containing $E$ we have $m^∗
(O - E) ≥ \epsilon$. By the definition of
outer measure, we know that there exists a countable collection of bounded open intervals
$\{I_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ whose union we denote $O ≡ \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}
I_k$, such that $m^{∗} (O) − m^∗ (E) < \epsilon \leq m^∗ (O - E)$.

[The source of the solution given above is found here.](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~punshs/Analysis-Solutions/HW2-Sol.pdf)

Comment: Idon't understand the last line.  By the definition of outer measure, we know that there exists a countable collection of bounded open intervals $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ whose union we denote $O ≡ \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k$, such that $m^{∗} (O) − m^∗ (E) < \epsilon$.  I don't see that in the def'n of outer measure in the book.

Comment: @NinosławCiszewski Since the outer measure is an infimum (i.e. greatest lower bound) then there must exist an open interval cover with sum of lengths $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\ell(I_k)} < m^*(E) + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ since otherwise $m^*(E) + \epsilon$ would be a greater lower bound than $m^*(E)$ which would be a contradiction. Combined with subadditivity of outer measure $m^*(E) + \epsilon > \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\ell(I_k)} \geq m^*\left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k \right)$ Just let $O = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k$ and you have the result about.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a dyadic mesh argument to construct a family of open sets each of which contains $E$, and then take their intersection.